# Javascript ReactJs Put JsCss and Component in external files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in the app index.js file.

As you can see its got some styles and also a button component.

Here is the full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//Styles Here
var buttonStyle1 = {
  margin: '10px 10px 10px 0',
  padding: '4px 20px',
  border: '1px solid grey'
};

var buttonStyle2 = {
  margin: '10px 10px 10px 0',
  padding: '4px 10px',
  border: '1px solid blue',
  borderRadius: 0
};

//Component Here
var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <button
        name={this.props.name}
        className={this.props.className}
        style={buttonStyle1}
        onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.label}
      </button>
    );
  },
  handleClick: function() {
     alert('Button pressed name is: '+ this.props.name);
  }

});

module.exports = Button;


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Button name="button1" label="Button" className="btn btn-success" />
    <Button name="button200" label="Label Here" className="btn btn-default" />
    <Button name="button20" label="Label again" className="btn btn-default" />
  </div>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What I nee to do is to add the part where it says //Styles Here into an external js file and the same to the part where it says //Component Here so they are both on external files.

How can I do this?

```
**//Update:**
```

***Here's the current code all now in the same level as index.js***

```
//index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Button from './Buttons';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Button style={{fontSize: '14px'}} name='Hi' label='button'/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

//ButtonStyles.js
module.exports = {
  buttonStyle1 : {
     margin: '10px 10px 10px 0',
     padding: '4px 20px',
     border: '1px solid grey'
  };

  buttonStyle2 : {
     margin: '10px 10px 10px 0',
     padding: '4px 10px',
     border: '1px solid blue',
     borderRadius: 0
  };
} 

//Buttons.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <button
        name={this.props.name}
        className={this.props.className}
        style={this.props.style}
        onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.label}
      </button>
    );
  },
  handleClick: function() {
     alert('Button pressed name is: '+ this.props.name);
  }
});
```

No button is showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the separate file for `Button` component, `button.js` like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <button
        name={this.props.name}
        className={this.props.className}
        style={this.props.style}
        onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.label}
      </button>
    );
  },
  handleClick: function() {
     alert('Button pressed name is: '+ this.props.name);
  }

});

export default Button;
```

And import this file wherever you want like this:

```
import Button from './button' //path to file
```

Use it like this:

```
<Button />
```

For styling, create a file `style.js`, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  buttonStyle1 : {
     margin: '10px 10px 10px 0',
     padding: '4px 20px',
     border: '1px solid grey'
  },

  buttonStyle2 : {
     margin: '10px 10px 10px 0',
     padding: '4px 10px',
     border: '1px solid blue',
     borderRadius: 0
  }
}
```

import this file like this:

```
import Style from './style' // path
```

And use it like this:  `<p style={Style.buttonStyle2}></p>`

Let me know if you need any help in this.

check the `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/jty8rggk/

Comment: Followed your instructions and here's my index.js: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Button from './components/Buttons';
import Style from './compoents/ButtonStyles';


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Button style={Style.buttonStyle2}></Button>
  </div>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);  ..it's not showing anything

Comment: because you are not passing any props values, try this:  `ReactDOM.render( 
    <div> 
        <Button name='Hello' label='World' style={Style.buttonStyle2}></Button> 
    </div>, document.getElementById('root') 
)`

Comment: since you want to pass the style also through props, then you have to change this line in button component: style={buttonStyle1} instead of this write this: `style={this.props.buttonStyle1}`

Comment: button comp that i created require these props: `name, label, style, className` pass all these values it will work :) did small change in button component, use the updated code.

Comment: Paths are: root: index.js  ... then everything else is in components folder

Comment: See current code under: Here's the current code all now in the same level as index.js updated

Comment: put this code in ur index.js file it should work, http://pastebin.com/FZ1gQDAt   
since you defined you button component in same file, in that case importing is not required. and u imported react and reactDom twice, remove the other one :)

Comment: Doesn't work either, I get this error: Error: Cannot find module "./src/index"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134965/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-paultenna2000).

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called ButtonStyles.js:

```
//ButtonStyles.js
export default {
    buttonStyle1: {
        margin: '10px 10px 10px 0',
        padding: '4px 20px',
        border: '1px solid grey'
    },
    buttonStyle2: {
        margin: '10px 10px 10px 0',
        padding: '4px 10px',
        border: '1px solid blue',
        borderRadius: 0
    }    
}
```

After that you can create a file for your component called `Button.js` and then import and use the styles in your component like below.

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './ButtonStyles'

//Component Here
var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <button
        name={this.props.name}
        className={this.props.className}
        style={styles.buttonStyle1}
        onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.label}
      </button>
    );
  },
  handleClick: function() {
     alert('Button pressed name is: '+ this.props.name);
  }

});

module.exports = Button;
```

Comment: Not getting any buttons... import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Button from './components/Buttons';
import Style from './compoents/ButtonStyles';


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Button style={Style.buttonStyle2}></Button>
  </div>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: that's my index.js above